# Why do Singleton's capture an instance of themselves?

Tags: swift, static, singleton

I'm trying to understand what happens at a lower-level when we create the first instance of a Singleton object within the Singleton's own class declaration.

As I understand it, the `static` keyword allows the marked property or method to be shared across all instances of a class, which I'm sure has a role here that I'm not seeing fully.

Additionally, how does this work when we consider the instance's creation during compilation/runtime?

Here's an example of a Singleton class declaration:

```
class Person {
    static let details = Person()
    var name = "Alan Turing"
    let age = "42"
}
```

I understand that the class and its properties will only be created once and that any reference to the class object will point back to that same point in memory. My confusion is specifically about why we create the Singleton's first instance within itself.

Comment: where else you would want to create this instance? you can create it where you want

Comment: The whole point of the singleton pattern is to have only one instance, and to stop any more instances from being created. If you allow instances to be created outside of the class, you can't prevent people from creating a second or a third instance, can you?

Comment: Also it's lazy, it only get init the first time you called it

Comment: Great points! I didn’t think about it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `static` variables are class variables that are always accessible via the class itself.
I suggest reading a more in depth explanation of `static` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

By having a static variable inside the class that contains an object of the class itself you ensure that at runtime there already is an object of that class (or at least at the time of accessing `Person.instance` for the first time).
For a true `singleton` inside Swift it is mandatory to make the `init` of that class `private` though, like so:

```swift
public class Person {
    static let instance = Person()
    var name: String
    let age: Int

    private init() {
        self.name = "Alan Turing"
        self.age = 42
    }
}
```

That way you ensure that there really is only one object present at any give time (hence the name `singleton`).